# Install OpenStack: ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (***?): No module named angular_fileupload

Tags: python, openstack

I was trying to build openstack (stack.sh), tried many times, still can't figure out the reason, below is the logs:

```
2016-09-08 05:36:48.424 | Warning: Could not import Horizon dependencies. This is normal during installation.
2016-09-08 05:36:48.425 | WARNING:root:No local_settings file found.
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 | Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/opt/stack/horizon/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     utility.execute()
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     settings.INSTALLED_APPS
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     self._setup(name)
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 |     % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
2016-09-08 05:36:48.426 | ImportError: Could not import settings 'openstack_dashboard.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named angular_fileupload
2016-09-08 05:36:48.450 | + exit_trap
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to make sure you have `pip` installed, if you've bootstrapped using Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install python-pip -y` where the -y flag is simply to accept any packages and prepare them for installation.

If you are using CentOS or any other Redhat based system `yum install -y python-pip`

Once this is done you need to go to `cd horizon/` where horizon is the folder you've just downloaded using git.

Should look like this:

```
fueladmin@nodename:~/horizon$ ls
AUTHORS             LICENSE              run_tests.sh
babel-django.cfg    Makefile             setup.cfg
babel-djangojs.cfg  manage.py            setup.py
build               MANIFEST.in          static
ChangeLog           node_modules         test-requirements.txt
CONTRIBUTING.rst    openstack_dashboard  test-shim.js
doc                 package.json         tools
HACKING.rst         README.rst           tox.ini
horizon             releasenotes
horizon.egg-info    requirements.txt
```

If you are familiar with node package management, composer or ruby gems you'll soon understand that requirements.txt is the python equivalent to something like package.json or composer.json i.e. it's where all the packages that needs to be installed are located.

Run this command `pip install -r requirements.txt` in the horizon/ folder and it should install. You may need to run it as sudo.

Once this is done you can proceed, firing up the server, configuration etc.

Comment: This is not so much an Openstack / Horizon question as it is a django or general python question though.